# How to understand what table/row is involved in LCK_M_U RID: 7:1:11826:0?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is RID: 7:1:11826:0?

It seems that 7 is the database_id from select * from sys.databases but what are another numbers mean?

This information comes from select * from master..sysprocesses with (nolock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RID is a row locator when a table is a heap (no clustered index). The numbers are:

```
database_id : file_number : page_number : slot_number
```

To read this page and figure out what data is there, you can do:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604, -1);
GO
DBCC PAGE(7, 1, 11826);
-- db_id -^
-- file_no --^
-- page_no -----^^^^^
GO
DBCC TRACEOFF(3604, -1);
```

In the output you should see something like this:

```
Metadata: ObjectId = <some number>
```

So then you can say:

```
SELECT s.name, o.name
  FROM sys.objects AS o
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE o.[object_id] = <that number from above>;
```

You can also see what that SPID last executed by saying:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<spid from sysprocesses>);
```

(As an aside, you really shouldn't be using `sysprocesses` anymore; that is a deprecated view that is only present for backward compatibility reasons. There are better dynamic management views available now, such as `sys.dm_exec_requests`.)

*Note: DBCC PAGE is undocumented and unsupported, though [Paul Randal blogged about it ages ago, when he worked for the SQL Server team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/10/625659.aspx). This is merely meant to give you an opportunity to see what object this page belongs to and what is stored on it. We have no way to know that.*